# Method is not compatible with method intelephense(1038)

Tags: php

VSCode doesn't accept a child and parent method with the same name but they have the same purpose.
The book I use doesn't use different name for this exercise and I don't understand why it doesn't work with me.
I found a solution by giving a different name to the child method but it doesn't help me to understand the problem.

**Index.php**

```
function monAutoLoad($class) {
    include(str_replace("\\", "/", $class). ".php");
}

spl_autoload_register('monAutoLoad');

use MesProduits\Produit;
$ordinateur = new Produit("ordinateur",10,1200,false);
echo $ordinateur . "<br>";
echo $ordinateur->supprimerProduit(5) . "<br>";

use MesProduits\ProduitParLots; 
$cartouchesEncre=new ProduitParLots("Cartouches d'encre",3,50,false); 
$cartouchesEncre->setNbArticlesParLot(10); 
$cartouchesEncre->ajouterProduit(6);
echo $cartouchesEncre . "<br>";
```

**Produit.php (parent class file)**

```
namespace MesProduits; //donner le même nom que le dossier parent


class Produit{
    protected $nom = "mon produit";
    protected $quantite = 10;
    protected $prix = 120;
    protected $rupture = false;

    function __construct($nom,$quantite,$prix,$rupture)
    {
       $this->nom=$nom; 
       $this->quantite=$quantite;
       $this->prix=$prix;
       $this->$rupture=$rupture;
    }

    function __toString(){
        return "nom: " . $this->nom . "<br>".
                "quantité: " . $this->quantite . "<br>". 
                "prix: " . $this->prix . "<br>". 
                (($this->rupture)? "no stock <br>" : "in stock <br>");
    }

    function ajouterProduit($quantite){ //parent method and I want the same name in the child file
        $this->quantite+=$quantite;
        if($this->quantite >=0){
            $this->rupture = false;
        }
        return "a product has been add <br>" . 
                "there is: " . $this->quantite . " in stock <br>";
    }

    function supprimerProduit($quantite){
        $this->quantite-=$quantite;
        if($this->quantite <=0){
            $this->rupture = true;
        }
        return "a product has been removed <br>" . 
                "there is " . $this->quantite . " in stock <br>";
    }
}
```

**ProduitParLots.php (child file class)**

```
namespace MesProduits;

class ProduitParLots extends Produit{
    private $nbArticlesParLot;

    function getNbArticlesParLot(){
        return $this->nbArticlesParLot;
    }

    function setNbArticlesParLot($valeur){
        if(!is_integer($valeur)){
            echo "the property must be an integer <br>";
        }else{
            $this->nbArticlesParLot=$valeur;
        }
    }

    function ajouterProduit2(){ //need to choose a different name for the child method
        $this->quantite+=$this->nbArticlesParLot; 
        if($this->quantite>0) $this->rupture=false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the "child" method has not the same signature as the parent method. You missed the `$quantite` parameter.

```php
class ProduitParLots extends Produit
{
    function ajouterProduit($quantite) { /* ... */ }
}
```